# Create duplicates in a python dictionary (not keys, values)

Tags: python

The picture is the best way to explain my problem, but I'm trying to populate a dictionary object in python, such that each key in the dictionary has a value of a list. Currently, all keys point to the same list. This is not what I want. Instead, I want each key to be associated with an independent copy of that list. I don't want to change the list in dict1 and have that change also occur in dict.

If there is a better object for this kind of task that a dict, I would love to hear that advise as well.

I tried using a list (of lists), but this gave me the same error (which surprised me).

Thanks! A bit of a noob! Sorry!
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15818688/IMAG0449.jpg

Comment: I would suggest posting this on StackOverflow instead, since this is more about programming than statistics. (You may find [this document](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) interesting, in particular `[:]`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the slicing operator to make shallow copies of your list.

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> d = {1:mylist[:], 2:mylist[:], 3:mylist[:]}
>>> d
{1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: [1, 2, 3]}
>>> d[1][0] = 23
>>> d
{1: [23, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: [1, 2, 3]}
>>>
```

If your values are more complex than a list of scalars, look into the [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

You're issue is happening because you're basically passing in references of the same list. Wrap your lists with "list()" (or use mylist[:] notation as mentioned in another answer) before you pass them in.  That way, a new instance (a list at a different memory location) of the list is used.

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> a = {1:l, 2:l}
>>> a
{1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3]}
>>> l.append(4)
>>> a
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

The above shows that adding an element to the original list, modifies the lists in the dict.  This is because they are the same list (in memory).

```
>>> a = {1:list(l), 2:list(l)}
>>> l.append(5)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>>
```

The above shows that modifying the original list (by adding 5) does not change the lists in the dict.  They are separate lists now.